# How to split the file "mongod.log" on the daily basis?

Tags: mongodb, logrotate

Here I'm using mongodb database for my app to store the data. But the logs created by mongodb in the `/var/log/mongodb/logFileName` folder with file name `mongod.log` is of very big size. It is not easy to read it. Because it is of size `989 mb`. I have searched for it and find a way to do this by `logRotate` and after that I found how to apply that in mongodb documentation there is a topic on the log rotate. I have apply the solution but it will not create any new file and not save the old one. This [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/#start-a-mongod-instance-specifying-the-reopen-logrotate-behavior) is I'm following to do this. But today I check my mongodb log file is empty and it will be last modified at night 11:55:01 pm. But yesterday I will do nothing and not worked with the app.

Second Solution and I also posted it on mongodb slack channel [link](https://mongo-db.slack.com/archives/C0KQ3RP7H/p1547282653168900):-

I have tried this solution too.
I changed in my config file `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  logRotate: reopen
```

I also change in file `/etc/logrotate.d/mongod` insert some data like

```
/var/log/mongodb/*.log {
   daily
   rotate 30
   size 50M
   compress
   dateext
   missingok
   notifempty
   sharedscripts
   postrotate
   /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
  endscript
}
```

but it will not creating the logs on daily basis. Why?

Now please can you tell me that How I will split the huge file into parts on daily basis?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you specified parameters like dateext and left them empty. Keep your config simple, make it work in the simplest manner first, then you can optimize it.

For example

```
/var/log/mongodb/*.log {
   daily
   rotate 50
   size 50M
   postrotate
   /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
  endscript
}
```

Please note that the rotate parameter is important here. We are keeping it high so it doesn't remove the logs after reaching the rotate limit.

Comment: @mOverseer if I paste the same example in logrotate file you give me then It works?

Comment: @mOverseer tell me please will it works on the daily basis.

Comment: This is configured to work daily so it should do it. You can check out the [logrotate manual](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html) and [some examples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/logrotate.htm).

Comment: @mOverseer can you tell me that what is the meaning of all in example we are using like `daily` means  `enters days after I want to create a new file for the log`. somethin g like that. Can you do?

Comment: Daily means, it will run once a day, to rotate, rename, or move the logs(depending on what you want). Rotate means, it will rotate for X times, which roughly translates to rotating the .log as log.1, log.2, log.3, until it reaches X. Size, defines a crossing line for file sizes. So if the log file is not bigger than defined Size, it won't rotate. I think you should also check out maxsize and minsize. Again I strongly advise reading the man page which explains all of these in-depth.